# Why won't my code recognize this method of my Node object?

Tags: class, arraylist, methods, syntax-error, nodes

I have this node class which has an instance variable that is an array list which will hold all of its neighbors.

I have methods to set and get the instance variables, including my arraylist instance variable "neighborhood".

When calling the method `addNeighbor()~, my code gives me an error.  It's all syntax error stuff that it's yelling at me, but I'm not sure what is wrong with my code here.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Node {

    static Node parent;
    static char key;
    static int time;
    static ArrayList<Node> neighborhood = new ArrayList();

    public Node(char Key) {
        parent = null;
        key = key;
        time = -1;
    }

    public static void setTime (int x) {
        time = x;
    }

    public static void setKey (char x) {
        key = x;
    }

    public static void setParent (Node x) {
        parent = x;
    }

    public static void addNeighbor (Node x) {
        neighborhood.add(x);
    }

    public static int getTime (){
        return time;
    }

    public static char getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public static Node getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Node> getNeighborhood(){
        return neighborhood;
    }
}
```

Class lab7

```
public class lab7 {

    Node A = new Node('A');
    Node B = new Node('B');
    Node C = new Node('C');
    Node D = new Node('D');
    Node E = new Node('E');
    Node F = new Node('F');
    Node G = new Node('G');

    int time = A.getTime();

    A.addNeighbor(B);  // error occurs HERE


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

addNeighbor method is returning void you can't use outside method.

```
 public class lab7 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node A = new Node('A');
        Node B = new Node('B');
        Node C = new Node('C');
        Node D = new Node('D');
        Node E = new Node('E');
        Node F = new Node('F');
        Node G = new Node('G');

        int time = A.getTime();
        A.addNeighbor(B);

    }
}
```

Comment: thank you.  I realized it only works if I call it in the main.

Comment: @LoFitz546 it has to be called in a method

Comment: @LoFitz 546 thanks for accepting answer! If you don't mind can you do +1.